# SQL sum results by type

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering if there is a way to group the results sequentially by type until the different types were reached. It is hard to explain using words so maybe an example below will help.

- Sum the first three rows because they all have "buy" type;
- The system reaches different type, so now it sums all the "sell" type records until we reach "buy" type again.

| id | type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | buy | 2 |
| 2 | buy | 5 |
| 3 | buy | 3 |
| 4 | sell | 4 |
| 5 | buy | 3 |
| 6 | sell | 1 |
| 7 | sell | 1 |

Final result:

| id | type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | buy | 10 |
| 4 | sell | 4 |
| 5 | buy | 3 |
| 7 | sell | 2 |

The id of records does not matter, I care only about the type and quantity.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x there may be a way to do it with window functions. If not, you should do this in a client programming language, rather than SQL.

Comment: Tell us your MySQL version, just run `SELECT version();` and add it into your question.

Comment: I would like to hear an option for MySQL 8.x and 5.7 versions if there are any for the past one.

Answer (score 1):

First we mark every time there's a change in `type` using lag and ordering by `id`, and then we count to create distinct groups.

```
select    type
         ,sum(quantity) as quantity
from     (
          select  *
                  ,count(chng) over(order by id) as grp
          from   (
                  select *
                         ,case when type <> lag(type) over(order by id) then 1 end as chng
                  from   t
                 ) t
         ) t
group by grp, type
```

| type | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| buy | 10 |
| sell | 4 |
| buy | 3 |
| sell | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MXKLfLmt?hide=4)